# How do I get web2py to allow regular http?

Tags: python, http, ssl, https, web2py

I've got a basic web2py app running, as I'm making a simple website for my organization.  It's going to be extremely simple - there will be no user logins, no information, no databases, nothing - it's really going to be mostly static.  The only dynamic content will be a couple of scrapers showing what our group has been up to recently.  However, my web2py app seems to force every single connection to go over HTTPS.  I don't want this, because since I self-signed the SSL certificate for admin login purposes, every browser acts like my website is some malicious attack website because the SSL certificate isn't verified.  I want to allow normal connections to the non-admin, front-facing part of my site to use HTTP, but they always, no matter what browser I use or if cookies/history are cleared etc, redirect to HTTPS and trigger that "malicious website" warning all browsers seem to have.  I just want the site to allow normal HTTP.  Anyone know what I can do?

Comment: web2py does not force HTTPS by default, so this likely has to do with how you have configured your server or some code you have added/copied to a model file (e.g., `request.requires_https()`). You will probably need to explain how you have deployed your app and maybe show some code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Web2py 'One step production deployment' script under linux, then probably you have this in your script:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

You can change it to:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

And remove the RewriteCond and RewriteRule. Then your http connection will not be rewrite to https.